# C# tcp socket client server transfer multiple files problem

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, file-transfer

I have 2 applications, one is server-app and the other is client-app. both are on same computer.Client has one button. When this button is clicked, client starts downloading files from server.
The problem is, sometimes client side received all files successfully, but sometimes client side only received the 1st file then stop transferring. Is there something wrong with the code below? could any1 show me where I'm wrong? I'm just new to coding like this.
help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.
Here is the code:

When user click a button on client, client will send a request download files from server:

```
//client side
sendRequest("requestFiles ");
```

Server will prepare files for client to download after receive token requestFiles

```
// server side
if (execmd == "requestFiles")
{
    string[] fList = Directory.GetFiles(folderDir);
    for (int i = 0; i < fList.Length; i++)
    {
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fList[i]);
        string[] mDesc = new string[3];
        mDesc[0] = fi.Name;
        mDesc[1] = fi.Length.ToString();
        mDesc[2] = fi.FullName;
        string fileSend = "CommitRequest " + fi.Name + " " + fi.Length.ToString() + " " + usID + " " + mName;
        sendRequest(fileSend);
        ClientDownloadingFromServer(mDesc[2], mDesc[1], sock);
    }
    sendComment("AllUpDone");
    continue;
}
```

For each file needs to upload, server will send a token CommitRequest with details of the file (name, size) 
When client receives CommitRequest:

```
//client side
if (execmd == "CommitRequest")
{
    //get file name and file size
    downloadFileFromServer(sock);
    continue;
}
```

Method downloadFileFromServer at client:

```
//client side
private void downloadMapFromServer(Socket s)
{        
    Socket sock = s;
    //prepare directory rootDir to store file
    System.IO.FileStream fout = new System.IO.FileStream(rootDir + "\\" + fileN, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    NetworkStream nfs = new NetworkStream(sock);
    long size = int.Parse(fileS);
    long rby = 0;
    try
    {
        //loop till the Full bytes have been read
        while (rby < size)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            //Read from the Network Stream
            int i = nfs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            fout.Write(buffer, 0, (int)i);
            rby = rby + i;
        }
        fout.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ed)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A Exception occured in file transfer" + ed.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(ed.Message);
    }
}
```

Method clientDownloadFromServer at server side:

```
//server side
void ClientDownloadingFromServer(string fiPath, string fiSize, Socket s)
{
    string parm1 = fiPath;
    string parm2 = fiSize;
    try
    {
        FileInfo ftemp = new FileInfo(parm1);
        long total=ftemp.Length;
        long rdby=0 ;
        int len=0 ;
        byte[] buffed = new byte[1024] ;
        // Open the file requested for download 
        System.IO.FileStream fin = new System.IO.FileStream(parm1,FileMode.Open , FileAccess.Read) ;

        NetworkStream nfs = new NetworkStream(sock) ;

        while(rdby < total && nfs.CanWrite)
        {
             //Read from the File (len contains the number of bytes read)
             len =fin.Read(buffed,0,buffed.Length) ;
             //Write the Bytes on the Socket
             nfs.Write(buffed, 0,len);
             //Increase the bytes Read counter
             rdby=rdby+len ;    
        }
        fin.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying some times you only receive 1 CommitRequest, or you receive multiple CommitRequests but only get download one file?

Comment: the purpose of CommitRequest is to send file name and file size for client to prepare to receive the file from server, also make the client calls the download method. And I dont know how to check it. Debug isnt working for me. My problem is for example, server sends 2 files, abc.txt and def.txt, but client only receives abc.txt, and this file has size larger than the abc.txt on the server (1kb).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is related to treating receiving bytes as file bytes or token bytes. Your client code is trying to read bytes that are equal to buffer size. Server sends "CommitRequest" token and file bytes one after another. So let's say first file size is of 1200 bytes. Server will send these 1200 bytes followed by "CommitRequest" for second file followed by second file bytes. Now, client would read 1024 bytes of first file. And then it would read next 1024 bytes - but these bytes will contain remaining 176 bytes of first file, "CommitRequest" response from server and then first few bytes of second file. Your client code only takes first 176 bytes and ignoring next bytes that would have data for next file.

You can solve the issue in two ways - either by making sure that remaining bytes would be processed (this can be tricky because remaining bytes may have "CommitRequest" response partially) or re-structuring your solution so that each file transfer will be initiated only after client request.

Comment: Thanks for answer VinayC. I think I got what u meant. I forgot to mention that the problem also happens with a same set of files. For example, server sends 3 files file1, file2, file3. Sometimes client gets all 3 files, but sometimes client only got file1.

Comment: if I change it like this do u think it gonna work? client click download,server send a string with all file names and file sizes. client foreach filename in string, send request token with filename and call method download(downloadMapFromServer above).Server receives token request and filename, then search file with that filename then send file to client(ClientDownloadFromServer).So I change the for command from server to client.This gonna be hard cuz I have to get filename & size from the string.What do you think about this? will it fix the error? and is it effective? Thx 4 ur help again.

Comment: @PeteMerry, IMO, approach of requesting each file one by one sounds fine and is straight-forward. File names and size can be separated by some token sequence (such as ||) that you are unlikely to found in file name (and simple string.Split would get you list of files).

Comment: Thanks VinayC. For now I will try to implement that. But what is the reason why with a same set of files, there're times the code works but there're times it doesn't? Is anything wrong with download and upload code? Also if I tried to download many times the program stopped working. For example 1st time download file1, file2, 2nd time download fileA, fileB, 3rd... at 4th time program stopped,doesnt crash but stopped.

Comment: @PeteMerry, the way code is, its difficult to predict when its going to work and when it is not. This is because server code tries to transmit file after file. On client, it can be received in any number of set of bytes. For example, first file can be set 1, 2nd file can be set 2 etc or part of first file as set 1, remaining file + part of second as set2 and many such combinations.

Comment: Hey VinayC, thanks for your help. I did as you said and it worked fine but there's a little problem. I post the question here, if you have free time could you check it out? thanks again.

Comment: What if I want to send a list of files a time at server? I meant that I don't want to waste time to request server for each file.